# How to remove column and index rows from dataframe results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I remove the Empty DataFrame, columns and index line?

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
   print(df)
   if df.empty:
      print("There is no data availale.")
```

Here is the results:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Time, Name]
Index: []
There is no data availale.
```

I want the results to be just:

```
There is no data availale.
```

Comment: Remove the `print(df)` line and it won't print the df, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use len(df):

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
if len(df)<1:
    print("There is no data availale.")
else:
    print(df)
```